# Log modified memory locations when tracing with Ollydbg

Tags: ollydbg, debuggers

When you trace with Ollydbg it prints the register values near commands that modify them. Is there any way to get it to print some memory locations, of my choice, when modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which version of ollydbg v1 or v2
if you are using v2 then use **set protocol** and apply limit to range for read , write , or r/w
the snapshot shows a range of 0x00000000 to 0x7fffffff (whole user mode mode range )
[image]

this should log the memory access to that range as follows

[image]